# How did Starkiller maintain orbit?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

So I just saw TFA and was just wondering this about starkiller. How did it maintain orbit after destroying its Sun? I don't think that destroying a planets sun would be very good for it.

Comment: There are real-life planets without stars, you know...

Comment: Yeah I know there are rogue planets..But it doesn't make sense for such an important and expensive battle station to be floating around freely in space, and possibly getting destroyed by a collision with some other planet.

Comment: Even drained of its energy, the remnants of a star would still have mass, causing gravity, and keep things in orbit.

Comment: @phantom42 - the novelization very explicitly states that the system Starkiller was in became a **binary** after Starkiller Base went nova